# kafka-connect.service fails with new java version

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We faced the below issue appears to be due to the ciphers deprecated in the new upgraded java version from 1.8.0.181 to 1.8.0_242 and it looks like a problem in new version cryptography.

Kafka version is kafka-1.1.0-confluent5.3.1
Hadoop version is 2.6.5

```
trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.io.IOException: Login failure for kafkaflow@xxxxx.COM from keytab /home/kafka/.keytabs/cedp-prod/kafkaflow.keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Message stream modified (41)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.\u003cinit\u003e(DataWriter.java:346)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.\u003cinit\u003e(DataWriter.java:102)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.start(HdfsSinkTask.java:88)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:300)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: java.io.IOException: Login failure for kafkaflow@xxxxxx.COM from keytab /home/kafka/.keytabs/cedp-prod/kafkaflow.keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Message stream modified (41)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:963)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.\u003cinit\u003e(DataWriter.java:173)\n\t... 11 more\nCaused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Message stream modified (41)\n\tat com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:808)\n\tat com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:618)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:954)\n\t... 12 more\nCaused by: KrbException: Message stream modified (41)\n\tat sun.security.krb5.KrbKdcRep.check(KrbKdcRep.java:101)\n\tat sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.decrypt(KrbAsRep.java:159)\n\tat sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.decryptUsingKeyTab(KrbAsRep.java:121)\n\tat sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.resolve(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:308)\n\tat sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:447)\n\tat
trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.io.IOException: Login failure for kafkaflow@xxxxx.COM from keytab /home/kafka/.keytabs/cedp-prod/kafkaflow.keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Message stream modified (41)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.\u003cinit\u003e(DataWriter.java:346)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.\u003cinit\u003e(DataWriter.java:102)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.start(HdfsSinkTask.java:88)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:300)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: java.io.IOException: Login failure for kafkaflow@XXXX.COM from keytab /home/kafka/.keytabs/cedp-prod/kafkaflow.keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Message stream modified (41)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:963)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.\u003cinit\u003e(DataWriter.java:173)\n\t... 11 more\nCaused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Message stream modified (41)\n\tat com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:808)\n\tat com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:618)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)\n\tat javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:954)\n\t... 12 more\nCaused by: KrbException: Message stream modified (41)\n\tat sun.security.krb5.KrbKdcRep.check(KrbKdcRep.java:101)\n\tat sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.decrypt(KrbAsRep.java:159)\n\tat sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.decryptUsingKeyTab(KrbAsRep.java:121)\n\tat sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.resolve(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:308)\n\tat sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:447)\n\tat
```

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK?

Comment: Why are you running Kafka Connect on Hadoop servers anyway? Kafka Connect is best deployed in an edge node fashion - it only requires the Hadoop SDK for HDFS Connect and keytabs, not local access to any NameNode or DataNode.

Comment: yes, we are using openjdk and we are not running kafka on hadoop server, it is on separate server using hdfs connect.